# EntityFramework 6 Transaction.Rollback and Commit

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext, rollback

I have a requirement to make a Cancel Button that will rollback all changes since the last context save. I got it were the rollback worked on a button click. However, the DataGridView didn't reflect the change. If I quit the program I can see that no data was changed.

I got the following form to work ( I don't see any errors in the Output window ) however, everything I read says to wrap the context in a using statement. Does that still apply in this situation? I have used Rollback and commit in a save method try/catch but this plane ole' doesn't look right. What if I spawn to another Form, will it add to the current transaction or not?

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    private TestContext _context;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    private DbContextTransaction _transaction;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        _transaction.Rollback();
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _context = new TestContext();
        _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        SetupDataGridView();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _transaction.Rollback();
        _context = new TestContext();
        SetupDataGridView();
        _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        PersonDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _transaction.Commit();
        PersonBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
        _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupDataGridView()
    {
        _context.People.Load();
        ObservableCollection<Person> people = _context.People.Local;
        PersonBindingSource.DataSource = people.ToBindingList();
        PersonBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        PersonDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        PersonDataGridView.DataSource = PersonBindingSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about `DataGridView` but most grid views actually cache the data and only show differences on modifications to the list, instead of re-reading the data. They typically have a method to refresh, but otherwise try setting the `DataSource` to `null` then back to the list and see if it refreshes.

Comment: @Jcl, Thank you for your comment. The `DataGridView` has `Refresh()`, but that did not refresh the displayed values. I also changed the `Datasource` to `null` then set it back, but it also did not refresh the displayed values.

Comment: since you are loading a different `DbContext` into the `Datasource`, then, unless you are doing something wrong at some other place, I see no reason at all why that shouldn't work. I don't have time to make a test project right now... if noone answers to give more possibilities, I'll try to make a simple one tomorrow and try it.